# Reset Panels in Google Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am going crazy here. I was using DevTools to debug on an Android device, and when I closed out of the inspector tool, I found that all of my panels are now horizontally stacked.

This is how it currently looks:

[image: now]

This is how it SHOULD look:

[image: ok]

Notice how the attributes panel is on the right side. I have been struggling to fix this for hours and it's driving me crazy.

Does anyone know how to completely clear any preferences for Chrome DevTools, as a backup? I feel like the device inspector may have changed this setting but there is no way to revert it.

Answer (score 1):

Click `...` , go to Settings, and look for `Panel layout` option:

[image]

P.S. Well, I feel silly. I checked back one more time in the options panel and I found it. Posting the answer to anyone who may find this post.

Comment: Has anyone found a way to rest the tools all together. On a multiscreen display. It appears that my dev tools have completely disappeared...

Comment: I'm late to the party, but I had an issue yesterday where the console was minimized when I visited one specific domain. When I hovered over the border, no selector appeared to increase the size. Switching to bottom layout and then back to right side layout fixed the issue.

Comment: Note in the above steps, increasing the height of the console panel before switching back to the original view seems to be the trick.